# How to create an alias with relative pwd + string

Tags: linux, command-line, alias, pwd

I want to set an alias to switch from two WordPress instances on the CLI. Each of them have the same paths except for the names of their respective sites e.g:

```
srv/deployment/work/sitename1/wp-content/uploads/2018/
```

```
srv/deployment/work/sitename2/wp-content/uploads/2018/
```

How do I create an alias that takes the "pwd" of the current location and cd
s to exactly the same location on the other site?

Comment: can you accept relative paths? or do you only accept PWD to be used?

Comment: I could accept relative paths (from "wp-content/.....). And then add the initial part of the path with a string and concatinate it. Not sure how though in bash.

Answer (score 1):

How about a bash function instead of an alias, gives you a little more freedom.

Save this bash function to a file like `switchsite.sh`. Modify the variables to your needs. Then load it into your bash with:

```
source switchsite.sh
```

If you are in `/srv/deployment/work/sitename1/wp-content/uploads/2018`, do

```
switchsite sitename2
```

and you will be in `/srv/deployment/work/sitename2/wp-content/uploads/2018`.

```
switchsite() { 
    # modify this to reflect where your sites are located, no trailing slash
    where_my_sites_are=/srv/deployment/work
    # modify this so it includes all characters that can be in a site name
    pattern_matching_sitenames=[a-z0-9_\-]
    # this is the first argument when the function is called
    newsite=$1
    # this replaces the site name in the current working directory
    newdir=$(pwd | sed -n -e "s@\($where_my_sites_are\)/\($pattern_matching_sitenames\+\)/\(.*\)@\1/$newsite/\3@p")
    cd $newdir
}
```

How it works: The sed expression splits the output of `pwd` into three parts: what is before the current site name, the current site name, and what comes after. Then sed puts it back together with the new site name. Just make sure the pattern can match all characters  that could be in your site name. Research [character classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) for details.

Comment: Hi, what I ended up doing was creating two bash scripts and replacing the sitename1 with sitename to with:

   `#;!/bin/bash`
    `current=$(pwd)`
   `switch="sitename1"`
   `cd ${current/sitename2/$switch}`

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines into `~/.bash_aliases`

```
export sitename1=srv/deployment/work/sitename1/wp-content/uploads/2018/
export sitename2=srv/deployment/work/sitename2/wp-content/uploads/2018/
```

After that

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Then you can simply type `sitename1` and `sitename2` from anywhere to switch to respective directories

Comment: That's not exactly what I want to do. The path example I gave was just to show I want to go from one locationt to the exact same location on the other site. I want to go from anywhere on one site to the other

Comment: no, now you have 2 variables, `$site1` and `$site2`. you'll still need to type `cd $site1` etc to use them. I would make an addtional alias for each like `alias site1='cd $site1'`. Good luck.